# Agents calling agents

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to wrap my head around what happens when agents call agents.

```
(def top (agent 0))
(def bottom (agent 1))
```

I have a minimal pair:

```
(defn testA []
  "This returns 'top', whose value is 'bottom', whose value is 2."
  (send top (fn [top-value]
          (send bottom inc)))
  (await top)
  top)

(defn testB []
  "This never terminates."
  (send top (fn [top-value]
          (send bottom inc)
          (await bottom) ;;<- this is new
          bottom))
  (await top)
  top)
```

What is happening with the inner await? What factors come into play when one agent calls another?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you cannot use `await` in agent action.  You can see the error (if you break from current waiting) with `(agent-error top)`

For longer answer (explaining why you can't do that) you'll have to (a)wait some clojure guru :)  My take is, that you can introduce dead-locks or some other disaster.

Also note, that using `top` or `bottom` returns the agent itself, not its value.  To get the value, you need `(deref top)` or `@top` for short.